# How to get location in android using CommonWare?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, broadcastreceiver, android-service

Can somebody share a working code of using Commonware jar library for android project.

I have downloaded the code from 
https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll

I really like the concept of getting the location on timely but I am unable to get it done using this library...plz help......

manifest entry

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller" />
<service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerService" />
```

code in activity

```
private void initLocationTracker()
    {
        try{
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerParameter locationPollerParameter =
                                                                        new LocationPollerParameter(bundle);

            locationPollerParameter.setIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion(new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class));

            // try GPS connection now

            locationPollerParameter.setProviders(new String[]
                    {LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER});

            locationPollerParameter.setTimeout(60000);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),PERIOD,pendingIntent);


            Toast
                    .makeText(this,
                            "Location polling every 30 minutes begun",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String s = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

**Edit:**
The code works fine but and executes as expected but I am unable to receive the broadcast in LocationReceiver.

Answer (score 5):

First, that is not "Commonware jar library for android project". That is Alex Birkett's fork of a "Commonware jar library for android project".

Second, as is explained [on the Web page that you linked to](https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll):

> In the `demo/` sub-project you will find a sample activity that demonstrates the use of `LocationPoller`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the issue is that when I execute the above code it works fine, I can see the toast but after that I couldn't anything in the LocationReceiver.

Comment: @Shax: Start by getting the `demo/` project to work. If you cannot get the `demo/` project to work, take it up with Mr. Birkett, as I cannot really help with his fork. If you *can* get the `demo/` to work, determine where your code and the `demo/` code differs.

Comment: I am using IntelliJIdea, when ever I try to open the demo it prompts me a window and asking me to enter a value agains this property _android_LocationPoller_b2bdace1. I dont know what is that...I am new android world....so plz forgive me if I am asking very idiotic questions